# Phaser 3 share custom object data between scenes?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have a class custom object in my GameScene.

```
this.player = new Player(
      this,
      this.game.config.width * 0.5,
      this.game.config.height * 0.5,
      "playerShip"
    );
```

This object has lives and score. Which is the best way to pass all the player data into another scene? I have tried to store it into localstorage and get the data in the different scenes but it loses all the class properties. I cannot pass the data as a parameter because after every scene comes 2 dialogue scenes and then the new playing scene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method I like to use is the `Phaser.Plugins.BasePlugin`.

```
class Player extends Phaser.Plugins.BasePlugin {
    constructor(pluginManager) {
        super(pluginManager); 
        //initialize player state
    }
    //Additional methods for getting managing player data
   isAlive() { return true; }
}

//in your JS entry file
let config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    parent: 'game'
},
    plugins: {
        global: [ //make the Player global to all scenes (and other plugins)
            // key is plugin key, plugin is class, start true/false if there
            // is a start method to run, mapping is the name tagged of this 
            // to access the plugin class
            { key: 'Player', plugin: Player, start: false, mapping: 'player'}
         ]
     }
 };

//In the scene 
class MyScene extends Phaser.Scene {
    
    update(){
         if(this.player.isAlive()) {
              //do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

I have also enabled stored state to local storage for my plugins. This can be useful for plugins related to quest state of player inventory progress between game sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Local storage, and any in-game storage like the game registry or game cache, all serialize data. You’re losing these class properties when serializing for these storage mechanisms.

If you want to hydrate from persistent storage, you’d need to construct a new class with the serialized data each time it is persisted and hydrated from some storage mechanism.

In order to preserve the object references to these classes between serializations, or as an alternative to hydration from state, you need to store a reference somewhere globally.

You can extend the Phaser.Game class to make things more type-safe, but it seems like the phaser game instance allows extension for a quicker solution. Just add a reference to your class instance and you can access it in any scene. [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/share-non-serializable-data-phaser-3-so)

Answer (score 0):

`DataManager` [class](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Data.DataManager.html) can be used to share data between scenes.

Look at [this example](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/scenes/registry-data-exchange).